# Select a default value of a combobox extjs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to select a default value of my combobox. I have tried using `value: 'Minor'` But this didn't help as when I try to retrieve the value it gives me Minor. in my combobox display is Minor and value is 1.

I have also looked at other selections like forceSelection but those didn't help either. Please look at the top left cell (which has the value of minor) in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2h86).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and don't just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I'll keep that in mind next time. Sorry

Comment: Update the question with all code snippets please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `valueField` to `value` but you are setting `text` as combo default value

Change `value` to '1'

```
value: '1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But if I do that then the display would change from "Minor" to '1'. wouldn't it? I want display to be "Minor" and value be '1'